# How to convert a dict to a dataframe, with the values as headers and rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I've recently run into a return from an API call where the return format is a list of dictionaries but the formatting causes the pd.DataFrame() to come out wrong.  I get a return format of:

```
{'name': 'a1', 'value': 'b1'}
{'name': 'a2', 'value': 'b2'}
{'name': 'a3', 'value': 'b3'}
{'name': 'a4', 'value': 'b4'}
{'name': 'a5', 'value': 'b5'}
```

When i run pd.DataFrames on this is turns into:

```
name    value
a1      b1
a2      b2
a3      b3
a4      b4
a5      b5
```

I have tried using df.pivot(column='name', values='value') but that leads to a 5 x 5 df instead of just 1 row.
Ideally I would like to get it where the column names= dictionary[name] and the row value=dictionary[value]:

```
index a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
0     b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
```

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index to the "name" column, and then transpose the dataframe (to switch rows and columns)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(api_result)
df = df.set_index("name").T
```

You can also do this directly when creating the dataframe, using the `from_records` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(api_result, index="name").T
```